# How to solve: white lines over images in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have images that I am rendering as background images on divs. In other browsers other than IE, they render fine, but in IE, there are white lines over the images. Here's the html and CSS

```
.img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="img" style="background-image: url(....);"></div>
```

Any one know what can cause this?

Turns out when I remove the border on the images, the images render fine in IE. But I need the border....

Comment: Why do you have style attribute AND background in CSS, remove the inline style

Comment: The issue is not the inline style. It's the border. When I remove the border, the images render fine in IE

Comment: But it is still unhealthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking a guess here as I don't have IE, but it seems to be doing something funky with the border on the background image.  My suggestion would be to wrap it in a div that has the border, and have no border on the img itself...

```
.img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.imgContainer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="imgContainer">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(....);"></div>
</div>
```